# Proving Convergence without Ratio Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Without using the Ratio test, how would one prove the convergence (which is intuitive) of this summation?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}$$

My Approach:
I suspect that I must convert the series in the bottom as a fraction of factorials to eliminate the evens.

To do this, I will convert $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)$ into $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)}$ which divides the evens from $(2n)!$.
This leaves the sum as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

We can set up an inequality such that $a_{n}\geq{a_{n+1}}$:

Note that this is more of a hunch on intuition. Is there a better way for me to derive this assertion?
$$\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\geq\frac{2^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2}{(2n+2)!}$$
$$\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\geq\frac{2(2^n)(n+1)^2(n!)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}$$
$$\frac{2(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\geq1$$
$$\frac{n^2+2n+1}{2n^2+3n+1}\geq1$$
which holds for some value of $n\gt1$

The limit of the original series is where I have trouble with (in retrospect, I should have done this first to see if the limit even converges!)

So how would one go about determining convergence without Ratio test and certainly without higher level mathematics? Is my sequence of steps on point? How could I make this "more formal"? And how can I take the limit of the the equation inside the sum?

Comment: At the start you dropped the alternating factor $(-1)^{n-1}.$ Was this done because you're trying to show absolute convergence? [Note I'm not sure absolute convergence holds here anyway...]

Comment: Instead of Ratio Test you can use an explicit comparison.

Comment: For example, the $n$-th term has absolute value $\le (2/3)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @coffeemath If you have an alternating sequence and the limit approaches 0 then the magnitude of the next term must be less than the previous. Right?

Comment: @IanLimarta Besides magnitude goes to zero one also needs monotone decreasing magnitudes (each term greater than the next in magnitude) in alternating series test. But your series is absolutely convergent anyway.

Comment: @coffeemath That is exactly what I said, (at least for each subsequent term less than the previous term). "Magnitude going to zero" is the limit I suppose. These are the two conditions that are in my book, but you are much more experienced and better than me. Thank you :)

Comment: Now that I reread my 2nd to last comment, I see how I left that part out, but I did mention it briefly (an inequality) in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 2$,

$$
 \frac{ n!}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}\leq \frac{n!}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 4\cdots (2n-2)}=\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}=\frac n{2^{n-1}}\leq 10\cdot\frac{1.1^n}{2^{n-1}}.
$$

Comment: And last term is also $20 \cdot [1.1/2]^n$ so geometric series shows original series (absolutely) convergent. [+1]

Comment: Completely forgot about comparing! Either way, would it be possible to find the limit of my equation?

Comment: Oh wait. I used squeeze theorem for (2/3)^(n-1) as André said and took the limit. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @IanLimarta: You just quote the standard fact that if $|r|\lt 1$ then the geometric series $1+r+r^2+\cdots$ converges. So by Comparison your series converges absolutely, so converges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes I could do that (I like it better) but I was originally trying to find the LIMIT of it, so I used the squeeze theorem. Thank you,  your way is certainly much better! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^n n!^2}{(2n)!}=-\sum_{n\geq 1}n(-2)^n B(n,n+1)=-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}n(-2)^n x^{n-1}(1-x)^n\,dx $$
leads to:
$$ S = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{(2x^2-2x-1)^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(2x^2-2x-1)^2} $$
and by partial fraction decomposition, or the substitution $x=t+\frac{1}{2}$ 
followed by integration by parts, we get:
$$\boxed{\, S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} n!}{(2n-1)!!}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}\,\log\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}\approx 0.586782.\; }$$

Hence yes, it is convergent, and convergent to $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Used same idea from your previous answer to my question . It's a good approach. Do you use it a lot? It is taught, or is it an original approach ? @Jack D'Aurizio Also can you show me how you evaluated the sum please.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: Euler's beta function is a useful tool, yes, I use it quite a lot. In order to convert the series into an integral of a rational function, it is enough to recall that $\sum_{n\geq 1}n z^n = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ for any $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably less easy than Jack D'Aurizio's answer, we could identify that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^n$$ is the Taylor expansion of $$\frac{x}{x+4}+\frac{4 \sqrt{x} }{(x+4)^{3/2}}\,\sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$ from which follows the result.